# How to switch from the default active tab to another tab from a different page using JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, pagination

I have some pagination tabs on page 2. What I want to do is to be able to go straight to a tab that I choose by clicking a link in another page.

I am using Bootstrap for the buttons and the pagination, so that's where all the class names come from.

Page 1:

```
        <button class="btn"><a href="/html/page2.html#phone" class="text-white">Read More</a></button>
        <button class="btn"><a href="/html/page2.html#tablet" class="text-white">Read More</a></button>
        <button class="btn"><a href="/html/page2.html#copmuter" class="text-white">Read More</a></button>
```

Page 2:

```
        <div class="nav nav-pills">
            <a class = "nav-link">Electronics:</a>
            <a href="#phone" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">Phone</a>
            <a href="#tablet" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Tablet</a>
            <a href="#computer" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Computer</a>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content mt-3">
            <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id = "phone">
                some text about phones
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id = "tablet">
                some text about tablets
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id = "computer">
                some text about tablets
            </div>
        <div>
```

So I want to be able to click on the tablet link on page one and open up the tablet tab on page 2. No matter what link I click in page 1, it always just goes to the phone tab, presumably because it's set as the active tab.

I know JS is required to fix this, and I've tried looking before on Stack Overflow, but haven't found anything that helps. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `onload` and `onhashchange` could be used along with `location.search.replace(/^\?/, '')` in your case.

Comment: @StackSlave if you could elaborate further please, how would I go along doing this? I only know Javascript fundamentals, so this isn't too familiar with me, especially this method.